# sum $\vert i-j\vert^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

The following sum is not difficult to compute $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \vert i-j\vert$$

using $\vert i-j\vert=\max(i,j)-\min(i,j).$

Now let $S_n:=\sum_{i,j=1}^n \vert i-j\vert^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0.$

Is it possible to compute $S_n$?

Or otherwise do we have $$\frac{S_n}{n}\to \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \vert k\vert^{\alpha}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $[p,q]$ be a short hand for $\{ p, p+1, \ldots, q-1, q \}$.

Notice for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$\# \big\{\; (i,j) \in [1,n]^2 : |i-j| = k\;\big\} = \begin{cases} 2(n-k), & k \in [1,n-1]\\n,& k = 0\\0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This means for any function $f(x)$, we have
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n f(|i-j|) = n f(0) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)f(k) $$

When $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, we can express the sum of $m^{th}$ power of integers in terms of [Bernoulli poynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^m = \frac{B_{m+1}(n+1) - B_{m+1}(0)}{m+1}$$

This means when $\alpha$ is a positive integer, we have

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n |i-j|^\alpha
= 2\left[n \frac{B_{\alpha+1}(n) - B_{\alpha+1}(0)}{\alpha+1}
- \frac{B_{\alpha+2}(n) - B_{\alpha+2}(0)}{\alpha+2}\right]$$

For general $\alpha > 0$, I have no idea whether there are other closed form for the sum.

Comment: No idea. Even if it possible, I doubt the expression will be anything computational simple.